# Receiving an Internal Server Error when initializing Next js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-dom

I wanted to start getting into Next js, and I followed the tutorial on their site ([Next js Tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app)) to a t - with no luck. I run `npm run dev` and I receive the following messages on my console, and terminal respectively:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**and** Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I am running Node v.13.13.0, React version 16.13.1 and React-DOM version 16.13.1.
I've tried creating my own app from scratch using npx-create-next-app, and I get the exact same error.
I just want to get a Next js app up and running, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you call a react hook inside a if statement ?
Please share a piece of code for a better context.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify - This is my first time using Next js. I created the app, cd into the directory, and typed npm run dev. I haven't typed in any code at all. I would be happy to share the code that is included automatically in the project that I initialized. What would you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I was able to resolve it in the end. I was using GitBash as my command window which was causing the internal server error. Once I switched to windows cmd, everything worked fine.